# Exchange Web Services API 1.0 Error

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2007, ews-managed-api

I'm getting the following error when trying to connect to my exchange server at Microsoft Online. I couldn't see how to get access to the underlying XML and I wondered if this error is caused because exchange is just serving the standard OWA login form, rather than an XML response that the EWS API expects. How can I check this?

This is the error, thrown on the the last line of my code:
'>' is an unexpected token. The expected token is '"' or '''. Line 7, position 62.

This is my code:

```
Dim ews As New ExchangeService
ews.Credentials = New WebCredentials("mytestmailbox@mydomain.com", "mypassword")
ews.Url = New Uri("https://mysubdomain.microsoftonline.com")

'send a test message
Dim message As New EmailMessage(ews)
message.Subject = "Hello World!"
message.Body = "This is a test message"
message.ToRecipients.Add("some@email.com")
message.SendAndSaveCopy()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by changing the Uri to the following: https://servername/ews/Exchange.asmx

Comment: This answer easily has the greatest life-impact to answer-brevity ratio I've had for a *long* time. I would have saved *so* much time if I'd known this already - how did you discover this?

Comment: Well, I went looking - as it was the EWS API I had a look through the IIS manager on my box, found that EWS seemed to have its own folder - had a look through it and sure enough there was an asmx file. I did try the main folder beforehand though. Glad you found it helpful! It's actually a nice API. If you figure out how to display email addresses without them coming back encrypted I'd really like to know that one!

Comment: Interesting - I'm gonna take a look now. And let me know if you find an answer to this new one I've got: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191186/ews-error-when-updating-an-item-category

Comment: EmailMessage.Sender.Address worked fine for me with no encryption. Maybe I didn't really get your question!